# Is Elastic IP obligatiory for a NAT instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nat, elastic-ip

Is an Elastic IP obligatory for a NAT instance? Or can I just continue with a public IP?

The CloudFormation template samples (like the one [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/taking-nat-to-the-next-level-in-aws-cloudformation-templates/)) feature an elastic IP address but I am not a fan of assigning one if not really a must.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Elastic IP is not obligatory for NAT instance. You can continue with the Public IP address. Elastic IP requires when you go with the NAT Gateway.